# Git: How to get specified version of all files in a folder but not descendant folders given a commit ID

Tags: git

I'm trying to get the versions of all files in a folder (but not in subfolders) including deletions.

Given a git repo with the following history:

```
$ git log --oneline
e654806 (HEAD -> master) Adding content to bar files
e43071a 3rd commit
1686e2f 2nd commit
3f21424 Initial commit
```

Trying to check out a version with a deleted file (added in e43071a) fails with:

```
git checkout 1686e2f foo/*.txt
error: pathspec 'foo/5.txt' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

So I delete all files in `foo/` and checkout again

```
rm foo/*.txt
git checkout 1686e2f foo/*.txt
```

I was surprised to find that this gave me the version of all files both in foo and foo/bar from 1686e2f

```
$ git st
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   foo/1.txt
    modified:   foo/2.txt
    modified:   foo/bar/3.txt
    modified:   foo/bar/4.txt

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    deleted:    foo/5.txt
```

how would I go about only getting the file versions of 1686e2f in `foo` but not in `foo/bar`?

Comment: Note that `foo/5.txt` came about here because the *shell* (not Git) expanded `foo/*.txt`. Once you removed `foo` and its contents, your particular shell and its settings stopped expanding `foo/*.txt` and passed the literal string to Git. If you're using bash, you can set the shell's `failglob` option to remind you to quote glob characters (though that still leaves you with the Git weirdness with pathspecs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the `pathspec` section of the `gitglossary(7)` man page, which tells us:

> the rest of the pathspec is a pattern for the remainder of the pathname. Paths relative to the directory prefix will be matched against that pattern using fnmatch(3); **in particular, * and ?can match directory separators.**

So that's why you're getting both `foo/*.txt` and `foo/bar/*.txt`. If
you keep reading, you'll find that you can add flags to the *pathspec*
that modify that behavior:

> `glob`
>
> Git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for consumption by `fnmatch(3)` with the `FNM_PATHNAME` flag: wildcards in the pattern will not match a `/` in the pathname. For example, `Documentation/*.html` matches `Documentation/git.html` but not `Documentation/ppc/ppc.html` or `tools/perf/Documentation/perf.html`.

That means we can write this:

```
git checkout 1686e2f ':(glob)foo/*.txt'
```

And that will match *only* files in `foo/` with a `.txt` extension.